# doctrine2 no metadata classes to process

Tags: symfony

I'm in a deadend and can't seem to find my way out of this apparently simple problem.

I'm working with Symfony2 and trying to create a database table from an Entity that I generated with the `generate:doctrine:entity` command. But when I run `doctrine:schema:create` I always get a "No Metadata Classes to process" message like Doctrine can't find my entity.

I checked the database, the namespace, the annotations, tried creating other entities manually instead of by using the `generate:doctrine:entity` command but I always get the same result.

Here is my entity :

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 */
class Blog
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="blog", type="text")
 */
private $blog;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text")
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @param string $author
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set blog
 *
 * @param string $blog
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setBlog($blog)
{
    $this->blog = $blog;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get blog
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlog()
{
    return $this->blog;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param \DateTime $created
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set updated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updated
 *
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updated
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}
}
```

I'm getting out of ideas. I saw other similar questions but none that could help me. If someone knows what to do, I'd love your help ;)

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Symfony cache and rebooting your dev server to clear any possible PHP cache?

Comment: run [app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata]  or check your app/config/config.yml under doctrine and  orm if you have 
        auto_mapping: true

Comment: Yeah I had tried to clear the caches and restart the servers already to no avail. And my doctrine config does have the auto_mapping at true.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Something weird happened to me when I put my entity class in a directory called `Models`, so my namespace was:

> AppBundle\Models

But it didn't work.

So I removed that folder and create another folder exactly named `Entity` and it worked.

So try to remove `BlogBundle` and put your `Entity` folder right under you `Appbundle` folder

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time This error come because of entity path issue and cache
run command first

```
doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

and then try

```
doctrine:schema:create
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to remove Blogger from your namespace:

```
namespace BlogBundle\Entity;
```